# How to add custom animated popup button with html, css and js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing web design as part. and now I want to use  this button animation in my web design. When I add it its not loading as it is on the above link.

I want the button should use on a person below to get the details of him. I'm using like putting css in main.css file (came with the website) js in to main.js and adding the html on the page. but I'm getting the attached error.

[image]

```
'https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/obvKxm'
```

Comment: Hi there. The editor has a restriction on adding codepen links and the like, please do not work around it. We need questions to be self-contained here, so although you can keep the codepen, please put the main part of the code readers need to see in the question itself. Thanks.

Comment: Guys i dont understand, will i get any solution?

Comment: @Arun The CSS on the codepen is SCSS, and you can't put that into a regular CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the CSS on the codepen is SCSS and you can't put that into a regular CSS file.

Here is the compiled CSS.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://theartmad.com/wp-content/uploads/Dark-Grey-Texture-Wallpaper-5.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}
html.modal-active, body.modal-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  z-index: 1;
}
#modal-container.one {
  transform: scaleY(0.01) scaleX(0);
  animation: unfoldIn 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.one .modal-background .modal {
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: zoomIn 0.5s 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.one.out {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: unfoldOut 1s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.one.out .modal-background .modal {
  animation: zoomOut 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.two {
  transform: scale(1);
}
#modal-container.two .modal-background {
  background: transparent;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.two .modal-background .modal {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: scaleUp 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.two + .content {
  animation: scaleBack 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.two.out {
  animation: quickScaleDown 0s .5s linear forwards;
}
#modal-container.two.out .modal-background {
  animation: fadeOut 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.two.out .modal-background .modal {
  animation: scaleDown 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.two.out + .content {
  animation: scaleForward 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.three {
  z-index: 0;
  transform: scale(1);
}
#modal-container.three .modal-background {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
#modal-container.three .modal-background .modal {
  animation: moveUp 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.three + .content {
  z-index: 1;
  animation: slideUpLarge 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.three.out .modal-background .modal {
  animation: moveDown 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.three.out + .content {
  animation: slideDownLarge 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four {
  z-index: 0;
  transform: scale(1);
}
#modal-container.four .modal-background {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
#modal-container.four .modal-background .modal {
  animation: blowUpModal 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four + .content {
  z-index: 1;
  animation: blowUpContent 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four.out .modal-background .modal {
  animation: blowUpModalTwo 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four.out + .content {
  animation: blowUpContentTwo 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.five {
  transform: scale(1);
}
#modal-container.five .modal-background {
  background: transparent;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.five .modal-background .modal {
  transform: translateX(-1500px);
  animation: roadRunnerIn 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.five.out {
  animation: quickScaleDown 0s .5s linear forwards;
}
#modal-container.five.out .modal-background {
  animation: fadeOut 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.five.out .modal-background .modal {
  animation: roadRunnerOut 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.six {
  transform: scale(1);
}
#modal-container.six .modal-background {
  background: transparent;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.six .modal-background .modal {
  background-color: transparent;
  animation: modalFadeIn 0.5s 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.six .modal-background .modal h2, #modal-container.six .modal-background .modal p {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  animation: modalContentFadeIn 0.5s 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.six .modal-background .modal .modal-svg rect {
  animation: sketchIn 0.5s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.six.out {
  animation: quickScaleDown 0s .5s linear forwards;
}
#modal-container.six.out .modal-background {
  animation: fadeOut 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.six.out .modal-background .modal {
  animation: modalFadeOut 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.six.out .modal-background .modal h2, #modal-container.six.out .modal-background .modal p {
  animation: modalContentFadeOut 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.six.out .modal-background .modal .modal-svg rect {
  animation: sketchOut 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.seven {
  transform: scale(1);
}
#modal-container.seven .modal-background {
  background: transparent;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.seven .modal-background .modal {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: bondJamesBond 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.seven .modal-background .modal h2, #modal-container.seven .modal-background .modal p {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  animation: modalContentFadeIn .5s 1.4s linear forwards;
}
#modal-container.seven.out {
  animation: slowFade .5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}
#modal-container.seven.out .modal-background {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  animation: fadeToRed 2s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.seven.out .modal-background .modal {
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 162px;
  width: 227px;
  animation: killShot 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.seven.out .modal-background .modal h2, #modal-container.seven.out .modal-background .modal p {
  animation: modalContentFadeOut 0.5s 0.5 cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container .modal-background {
  display: table-cell;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal {
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal .modal-svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal .modal-svg rect {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 778;
  stroke-dashoffset: 778;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.content h1 {
  padding: 75px 0 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.content .buttons {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.content .buttons .button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.content .buttons .button:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #009bd5;
}

@keyframes unfoldIn {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
  }
}
@keyframes unfoldOut {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes zoomOut {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    background: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@keyframes scaleUp {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateY(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes scaleDown {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateY(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scaleBack {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.85);
  }
}
@keyframes scaleForward {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.85);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes quickScaleDown {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  99.9% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideUpLarge {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
@keyframes slideDownLarge {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
@keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes moveDown {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(150px);
  }
}
@keyframes blowUpContent {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
@keyframes blowUpContentTwo {
  0% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes blowUpModal {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes blowUpModalTwo {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes roadRunnerIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-1500px) skewX(30deg) scaleX(1.3);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translateX(30px) skewX(0deg) scaleX(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1);
  }
}
@keyframes roadRunnerOut {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-30px) skewX(-5deg) scaleX(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(1500px) skewX(30deg) scaleX(1.3);
  }
}
@keyframes sketchIn {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 778;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes sketchOut {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 778;
  }
}
@keyframes modalFadeIn {
  0% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
@keyframes modalFadeOut {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
@keyframes modalContentFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -20px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes modalContentFadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -20px;
  }
}
@keyframes bondJamesBond {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(1000px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    border-radius: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
  }
  90% {
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 182px;
    width: 247px;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 162px;
    width: 227px;
  }
}
@keyframes killShot {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(300px) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeToRed {
  0% {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgba(201, 24, 24, 0.8);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0 2000px 0 rgba(201, 24, 24, 0.8);
  }
}
@keyframes slowFade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh hoooo, great, any other idea or solution. I need to use the Bond animation? can you help me?

Comment: @Arun I edited the post with the compiled CSS, which you can just paste in.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. And any changes in js?

Comment: You would need jQuery - if you don't have it, add `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` to the `<head>` of your HTML.

Comment: @YvetteColomb SE's code blocks add scrollbars if it gets too long. Besides, where else would you put it? Could you guarantee that the data would still be there after 5 years? Because SE's data dumps will certainly be.

Comment: yea i will remove unwanted codes. thats not a problem

Comment: @OliverNi, can i use the js script or the jQuery is enough?

Comment: and Bond animation is not happening, to where i need to put the js. in head section or put in a file in the path?

Comment: @Arun You need both, but add an ID to the button to trigger the element and replace `.button` with `#idgoeshere`

Comment: @OliverNi, sorry i dint get, in css or html. I'm totaly confused with this dude....:(

Comment: Now i got the BOND button exactly. but only the popup is not working.

Comment: <div class="modal-background">
    <div class="modal">
      <h2>I'm a Modal</h2>
      <p>Hear me roar.</p>
      <svg class="modal-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="226" height="162" rx="3" ry="3"></rect>
       </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">

  <div class="buttons">
        <div id="seven" class="button">Bond</div>
  </div>
</div> above is the code is in html. need to change anything?

Comment: Add `id="animation-trigger"` to your button, and put this JavaScript in instead of the original one: https://hastebin.com/igonezihol.js

Comment: <div id="modal-container">
  <div class="modal-background">
    <div class="modal">
      <h2>I'm a Modal</h2>
      <p>Hear me roar.</p>
      <svg class="modal-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="226" height="162" rx="3" ry="3"></rect>
       </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">

  <div class="buttons">
        <div id="animation-trigger" class="button">Bond</div>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: above is the html code. any changes required. i think i had made a mistake i belive

Comment: @OliverNi I checked the 3 codes we modified in online webtester and there also getting the same.? need to change anything

Comment: Finaly it worked bro, with your complied css and older html and js. Thanks a lot. Now i need to change the position of the box and other things :)

Comment: @OliverNi How can we close the popup when we click on the webpage?